# how to join typed list and List<object> using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class CoordinatePoint
{
public double x { get; set; }
public double y { get; set; }  

}

var Events = new List<CoordinatePoint>();
Events.Add(new CoordinatePoint { x = 1, y = 10 });
Events.Add(new CoordinatePoint { x = 2, y = 20 });
Events.Add(new CoordinatePoint { x = 3, y = 30 });
Events.Add(new CoordinatePoint { x = 4, y = 40 });
Events.Add(new CoordinatePoint { x = 5, y = 50 });


var Data= new List<object>();
CorridorData.Add(new object[] { 1, 11});
CorridorData.Add(new object[] { 2, 21});
CorridorData.Add(new object[] { 3, 31});
CorridorData.Add(new object[] { 4, 41});
CorridorData.Add(new object[] { 5, 51 });
```

I need to join those two lists to calculate the sum where the primary key of List Events is `x` and for **List Data** is the first index.

Comment: Why is the second list not a `List<int[]>`?

Comment: What results are you expecting?

Comment: because i have many differents types inside this list in reallity , CorridorData.Add(new object[] { 1, 11 , 6 , false});

Comment: This isn't an advisable approach.... What if your `object[]` won't have the `x,y` for you to join? You will have to start checking the length of the array to make sure you have those cells and also the type of them. Better have a base class for the stuff that you want to have in that `List`

Comment: as result i expect 
{
 {1,21},
 {2,41},
 ....
}

Comment: @UndertakerBatista: you should really use a custom class with meaningful properties  instead of that `object[]` .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ.Join` method to accomplish what you want (despite that, I would recommend to review your architecture to make the code more clear):

```
var result = Events.Join(
  CorridorData,
  e => (int)e.x,
  c => ((object[])c)[0],
  (e, c) => new { x = (int)e.x, data = ((object[])c)[1] });
```

Please pay attention that in your Coordinate Point the coordinate is of `double` type and in your data you add `1` which is `int`. So if you want to join them you have to cast double to int (or vice versa) that could result into an unexpected behavior for you.

*Update:*

If you want to get `sum` use the next query:

```
var result = Events.Join(
  CorridorData,
  e => (int)e.x,
  c => ((object[])c)[0],
  (e, c) => new { x = (int)e.x, data = (int)((object[])c)[1] + e.y });
```

That will result exactly to what you have written in the comment:

```
1, 21.0
2, 41.0
3, 61.0
4, 81.0
5, 101.0
```

Note that there are a lot of places where it can throw an exception or just return 0 results if your `list` will became invalid (which compiler can't check as all of entries are `object`s).

Comment: thanks evrybody for helping , thanks Ivan Yurchenko thats exactly what i need ,